# Как правильно использовать nth-child и hover в этом задании?

Tags: html, css

Нужно создать страницу с 5 рядами и 6 людьми в каждом ряду. Наверх добавить изображение перчатки при наведении на которую каждый 2 человек должен пропасть, чтобы было так как на картинке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь доступно объснил и вы сможите мне как-то помочь выполнить это задание
заранее спасибо)

Comment: вот тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child написано как что-то применить на чётные или нечётные элементы. Осталось только расположить элементы в вёрстке и применить к корневому `.root-element:hover .children:nth-child(even) { ... }`

Comment: [тут видео про четные нечетные элементы](https://youtu.be/lHI1v4KLb2I) про селекторы в общем и примеры интересные

Answer (score 2):

```css
.items {width: 25px; height: 25px; background: green;}

div {display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr); grid-gap: 5px; margin: 5px 0;}

div>span {width: 25px; height: 25px; background: red;}

.items:hover~div:nth-child(2)>span:nth-child(odd),
.items:hover~div:nth-child(3)>span:nth-child(even),
.items:hover~div:nth-child(4)>span:nth-child(odd),
.items:hover~div:nth-child(5)>span:nth-child(even),
.items:hover~div:nth-child(6)>span:nth-child(odd) {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="items"></div>
<div><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
<div><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
<div><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
<div><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
<div><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
```